# Windows Authentication for a non-local non-domain Login

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  There is no domain in the network.

Is there any way for me to add a Windows Login on SQL Server for a non-local and non-domain user?  For instance, if the server is `Server1` and a PC on the network is `PC1`, how can I add `PC1\User1` as a Windows Login on the SQL Server instance installed on `Server1`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create matching usernames and passwords. It really is that simple. For your example, create an account for `User1` on `Server1` with the same password as on `PC1`.

Just in case this is an issue you're having with connecting SSMS with a non-domain account, that requires jumping through an additional hoop. Some applications don't support stored usernames and passwords via the windows credential store. SSMS is one of them.

I have a bunch of runas shortcuts to deal with connecting SSMS to a variety of servers in different domains:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe 
/netonly 
/user:DOMAIN\USER 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

You could also make use of the [SysInternals ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) extension.

Comment: FWIW it took a lot of teeth-pulling but I was ultimately able to get credential manager to pass Windows credentials from the store to the remote server using SSMS. I had to add the FQDN to my hosts file and then `ipconfig /dnsflush` before it would recognize and match the credential server name.

Comment: I can not get this to work.  Perhaps I am in a slightly different setup.

I am on my home machine, connected via VPN to work.  The work SQL server has Windows Auth only, and my domain username has rights.  I cannot connect this computer to the domain, or get it trusted by the domain.  But I need to login to SQL as my domain user somehow.  Runas does not seem to work for me at all...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Can you outline how you were able to get the credential manager to pass on the credentials to SSMS?  Currently, I connect like the OP does with `runas`, but then I need to enter the passwords again. It would be great if I could pass on the information stored in the credential manager.